# Angular JS AJAX Data and HTML Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement header menu section using AngularJS, now the data is coming but the `<div class="submenu">` is not working and hence the drop down is not working. Where am I going wrong ?

```
<nav ng-app="essotHeaderApp" ng-controller="essotHeaderController">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat-start="menuItem in menuList.menu" class="simple-list">
         <a ng-href="/category/{{menuItem.categoryID}}"  ng-bind='menuItem.categoryName'>Products</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
         <div class="submenu">
            <ul class="simple-menu-list-column">
               <li>temp</li>
               <li ng-repeat-start="subItem in menuItem.subCategories">
                  <a ng-href="/category/{{subItem.categoryID}}" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-bind='subItem.categoryName'>Details</a>
               </li>
               <li ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat-end class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat-end class="divider-vertical"></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <a class="fixed-header-visible additional-header-logo"><img src="img/logo-7.png" alt=""/></a>
</nav>
```

script ::

```
var essotHeaderApp = angular.module('essotHeaderApp', []);
 essotHeaderApp.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);
 essotHeaderApp.controller('essotHeaderController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
     $scope.searchText;
     $http.get('*************************').success(function (data) {
         $scope.loaded = true;
         $scope.menuList = data;
         console.log(data);
     }).error(function (err) {
         console.log(err);
     });
 });
```

Comment: And what does your javascript look like?

Comment: var essotHeaderApp = angular.module('essotHeaderApp', []);
essotHeaderApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
      }
 ]);

essotHeaderApp.controller('essotHeaderController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
  
  $scope.searchText;

  $http.get('*************************')
       .success(function(data) {
         $scope.loaded    = true;
         $scope.menuList  = data;
   console.log(data);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
   }); 
});

Comment: Please add it as a code block to your question.

Comment: What's the output in console?